# Sending Multipart files with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, multipart

I have two servers, where server A is sending files to server B. On server B i have an endpoint which recieves files of given category. This is signature of endpoint i need to send files to:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadMultipleFiles/{projectId}")
public List<UploadFileResponseDts> uploadMultipleFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, @RequestParam("categoryId") Long categoryId, @PathVariable("projectId") Long projectId) {
    return uploadMulitpleFiles(files, categoryId, projectId);
}
```

Now im having trouble creating such request with RestTemplate exchange. On Server A i'm trying to send files one by one (endpoint on server B needs to accept multipart array since its used somewhere else as well). This is what i tried:

```
public Optional<String> uploadFile(File file, Long projectId) throws Exception {

    String authToken = getAccessToken();
    String projectFileUploadEndpoint = fileUploadEndpoint + SEPARATOR + projectId;

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts =
            new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            parts.add("files", new ByteArrayResource(bytes));
    parts.add("categoryId", 0L);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set("Authorization", authToken);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity =
            new HttpEntity<>(parts, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response =
            restTemplate.exchange(projectFileUploadEndpoint ,
                    HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

this almost works, the only issue is that on server B `files` from `@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files` is always null. I assume that the issue is with the way im assembling `parts` in on my server A, however i cant find my mistake. Could you point it out?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller all is fine, the problem is about your client code.

Basically you should use `FileSystemResource` object instead of `ByteArrayResource`. 
The basic motivation is about file metadata. Using FileSystemResource spring is able to rebuild the required `MultipartFile` info, therefore the your code may be like below

```
  @Test
  public void contextLoads()
  {
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(file);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    parts.add("categoryId", 0L);
    parts.add("files", fileSystemResource);

    String serviceUrl = "http://localhost:8080/uploadMultipleFiles/0";

    RequestEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = post(fromPath(serviceUrl).build().toUri())
      .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
      .body(parts);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new ResponseErrorHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
      {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException
      {
        System.out.println(response);
      }
    });
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

    assertThat(200, Is.is(response.getStatusCode()));

  }
```

I hope that this test case can help you to solve the problem